# How to get specific frequency and time values for .wav file and export the values as .csv

Tags: audio, fft, audacity, praat

I am new here, so sorry in advance if I make any mistakes!

Problem: I need to analyze this music .wav file, particularly for its frequency, amplitude, and pitch over specific intervals of time.

Is there any easy to use software and steps I can take that can help me accomplish this?

I have tried audacity, sonicvisualizer, and sigview, but I am unsure how to utilize these softwares appropiately to achieve my specific goal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Software that does this accurately in the general case (especially for live acoustic or polyphonic music) is still a research project, thus not "easy to use".

Answer (score 2):

[Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) is good for these kinds of things. It has been specifically designed for speech research, but it can (and has) been used for analysing music as well.

It has a scripting language that allows for automation, and can analyse the things you mention for specific intervals or for the whole sound. Take a look at the documentation, specifically the sections on [Pitch](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Intro_4__Pitch_analysis.html), [Intensity](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Intro_6__Intensity_analysis.html), and [spectral](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Intro_3__Spectral_analysis.html) analysis.

Comment: I was able to get a XYZ data table that displayed time, frequency, and amplitude, but I'm not sure how to combine the frequency and  amplitude.

Comment: It really depends on what sort of combination you want to get, and for what. I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, really. Did you read the info on the links I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Sigview is super easy to use and is your best bet if you want to be the most  scientific about it (without investing too much $$ or time).

To use SigView, drag & drop an audio file into sigview. Highlight the portion of the waveform you're interested in and right click, select the option 'open selection in new window'. When you're looking at the portion of the waveform you're interested in, hit ctrl-f and it will perform an FFT on the segment. Right click and select show peaks so see the amplitude & frequency of each peak.